# What are the advantages of using a single integer for multiple for loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, scope

As the title suggests, what are the advantages of using this:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    <do stuff>
}

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    <do other stuff>
}
```

instead of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    <do stuff>
}

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    <do other stuff>
}
```

In other words, is there any advantage in not declaring another variable for each loop?

I would imagine that it takes less memory to store them, but they are both going to be scrapped at the end of the method, so why would it matter? (Or GC will just get rid of them)

Comment: In favor of limiting scope, you should always go with version 2.

Comment: unless you need `i` outside the loop, there's no value in the first approach over the second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both solutions will almost certainly take exactly the same amount of memory, and no heap memory is involved here (GC is irrelevant).

Even at the level of `javac` it can be easily determined when the local variable in your second case is out of scope (outside the `for` loop), and the location used for it can be reused for the other loop.

At runtime the variable will probably be assigned to a register and, subject to many details of the actual code and the JVM implementation, the loop will be unrolled or transformed in other ways, making it almost impossible to even make sense of the concept of "memory usage" of that variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining, I had a feeling that it would just reuse the same place used for the first variable.

Answer (score 3):

Just be aware that lazy programmers sometimes use the loop variable to determine if the loop completed correctly, e.g.:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    if (someRandomCondition)
      break;
}

if (i < 7)
 ... Oops, we exited early
```

This is obviously poor practice - better would be to retain this early exit status elsewhere, so if you are tidying up scope, refactoring may be required.

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage or disadvantage related to it...It is based on the need of that variable
If you require that variable everywhere in the class then it must be declared outside the methods or loop ..but if it is made only for the use of loop then there is no need to declare it first both will have almost same effect on memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea. The only difference is when the Variable becomes garbage.

In the first example the integer wil become garbage when the parent method completes. In the second example the integers will become garbage when each of the for loops finish.

If the language you are using has automatic garbage collection (Java) then declaring the int with the for loop might end up saving memmory. Later in the same parent method the int would be cleared out and you would not have to worry about that integer being allocated until the method completes.